# слишком много return Promise javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
 function send_cash_toClient_QIWI(){
    this.phone = this.tradeoffer.phone_number;
    this.amount = this.tradeoffer.amount;


    let msgProccess = (msg.send + this.phone + ' Количество: ' + this.amount + ' руб.');

    return this.message(msgProccess).then((text) => {


       return qiwi.send(One, this.amount, this.phone).then((status) => {

            if(status){
                console.log(this.id + ': ' + 'qiwi money was send');
                this.payed = true;

                this.save({'pay': true});

                return this.message(msg.success).then((status) => {
                    return client.markpaid(this.id).then((status)=>{
                 return ('Marked as Payed');
               })

                })

            } else {
           return ('error send cash');
        }
         })
      })

  }
```

каждая функция внутри функции send_cash_toClient содержит промис(return new Promise) и возвращает resolve, поэтому после каждой функции .then((status), и я вызываю эту функцию (send_cash_toClie....) через await/async вопрос не переборщил ли я с return , изначально я написал так

```
      function send_cash_toClient_QIWI(){
        this.phone = this.tradeoffer.phone_number;
        this.amount = this.tradeoffer.amount;


        let msgProccess = (msg.send + this.phone + ' Количество: ' + this.amount + ' руб.');
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.message(msgProccess).then((text) => {


             qiwi.send(One, this.amount, this.phone).then((status) => {

                if(status){
                    console.log(this.id + ': ' + 'qiwi money was send');
                    this.payed = true;

                    this.save({'pay': true});

                    this.message(msg.success).then((status) => {
                         client.markpaid(this.id).then((status)=>{
                     resolve('Marked as Payed')
                   })

                    })

                } else {
               resolve('error send cash')
            }
             })
          })
})
      }
```

Как правильно? и чтоб не было нагромождений

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вообще промисы сделали для того, чтобы избежать callback hell, поэтому стоит их в общую цепочку объединять:

```
function send_cash_toClient_QIWI() {
    this.phone = this.tradeoffer.phone_number;
    this.amount = this.tradeoffer.amount;
    let msgProccess = (msg.send + this.phone + ' Количество: ' + this.amount + ' руб.');
    return this.message(msgProccess)
        .then(text => qiwi.send(One, this.amount, this.phone))
        .then(status => {
            if (status) {
                console.log(this.id + ': ' + 'qiwi money was send');
                this.payed = true;
                this.save({ 'pay': true });
                return this.message(msg.success)
                    .then((status) => client.markpaid(this.id))
                    .then((status) => ('Marked as Payed'))
            } else {
                return ('error send cash');
            }
        })
}
```

Возвращая в then промис, его результат попадает в следующий then в одной цепи, а не в глубь.

Ну и в стрелочных функциях return коротких блоков пишется намного чище – `(a) => { return a; }` можно записать как `a => a`

Answer (score 1):

Можно переписать с использованием `await/async`, будет немного более читабельно.

```js
async function send_cash_toClient_QIWI() {
  this.phone = this.tradeoffer.phone_number;
  this.amount = this.tradeoffer.amount;


  let msgProccess = (msg.send + this.phone + ' Количество: ' + this.amount + ' руб.');
  try {
    const text = await this.message(msgProccess);

    const status = await qiwi.send(One, this.amount, this.phone);

    if (status) {
      console.log(this.id + ': ' + 'qiwi money was send');
      this.payed = true;

      this.save({'pay': true });

      const statusSuccess = await this.message(msg.success);
      const markpaidResult = await client.markpaid(this.id);
      return 'Marked as Payed';
    } else {
      return 'error send cash';
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return e;
  }

}
```